# srand generating the same number

Tags: c++, srand

PLEASE READ THE QUESTION CAREFULLY BEFORE DECIDING IT'S BEEN ANSWERED ELSEWHERE...
I'm not asking about a rand that's generating the same number... I'm asking why, when using srand, am I getting the same number? When calling roll, shouldn't the fact that I've included srand generate a new number every time roll is called? Am I implementing this incorrectly in the roll function? Please look at my code before just closing the question!

I'm writing a program meant to generate 10 random numbers between 1 and 6. I've made sure that srand() is in fact returning different numbers each time I run the program, but the same number is being generated for each roll in main. I've looked at other programs and they look to be written exactly as I've written mine. I've read through explanations on srand and rand and can't figure out what's going on here. Would really appreciate any insight!
die.h

```
//header guards
#ifndef DIE_H
#define DIE_H

class Die {
    public:
        // Randomly assigns a value to roll_value in the range of 1 to 6
        void roll();
        // Returns roll_value
        int rolled_value() const;
    private:
        // Stores a randomly assigned value
        int roll_value;
        // Die sides, initialized to 6
        int sides = 6;
};

#endif
```

die.cpp

```
#include "die.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void Die::roll() {
   srand(time(0));
   roll_value = rand()%sides + 1;
}
int Die::rolled_value() const {
   return roll_value;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "die.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using std::cout;

int main() {
  
   srand(time(0));
   int random = rand();
   cout<<random<<"\n";
   Die die;
   int i = 0;
   for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
   {
       die.roll();
       cout << "Roll #"<< i << ", Roll Value: " << die.rolled_value() << "\n";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Roll #1, Roll Value: 4
Roll #2, Roll Value: 4
Roll #3, Roll Value: 4
Roll #4, Roll Value: 4
Roll #5, Roll Value: 4
Roll #6, Roll Value: 4
Roll #7, Roll Value: 4
Roll #8, Roll Value: 4
Roll #9, Roll Value: 4
Roll #10, Roll Value: 4
```

Expected Output:

```
Roll #1, Roll Value: 6                                                                                                                                                                        
Roll #2, Roll Value: 5
Roll #3, Roll Value: 5
Roll #4, Roll Value: 6
Roll #5, Roll Value: 5
Roll #6, Roll Value: 1
Roll #7, Roll Value: 1
Roll #8, Roll Value: 5
Roll #9, Roll Value: 3
Roll #10, Roll Value: 6
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you expect that output particularly?

Comment: Given the number generated, [this is particularly fitting](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: @cigen I didn't expect those numbers exactly, I was just giving and example:)

Comment: One trick you may find later is testing with a fixed value for the seed. This way you can have multiple runs  of the program on the same random numbers and explore the program over and over under the same conditions. Very helpful in seeing if a bug fix really did fix the bug as opposed to the bug just not manifesting the same way with a different set of data.

Comment: Just randomly had 4 a lot of times.  Could happen.

Comment: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714)

Comment: yes, but my other runs returned all 6's or all 1's... it didn't seem like that would happen by random chance alone @elijay

Comment: You are initialising the rand with the same seed in `::roll()`.Waiting long enough (i.e. printing 1000 or a million rolls), you will see other values, as the time changes.